# Creating a nested list from a list

Tags: python, list, networkx, nested-lists

I have a text file that contains a list of twitter users and followers. Its has the twitter user in the first element and the follower, and it looks something like the below:

`(user, follwer1,follower2,follower3,....)`

I intend on doing some analyses on this using networkx, but before I can so that I need to reformat the data to a csv with 2 columns, where column 1 is the user (so this will be the user id repeated on every line) and the column b will be the follower (see below):

```
| User | Follower |
| -----|--------- |
| user | Folower1 |
| user | Folower2 |
```

Initally all of the data is stored as a string, so I have converted it to a list. What I was trying to do was convert this to a nested list that would look something like:

```
[[user,follower],[user,follower2],[user,follower3]....]
```

and then convert to a datframe and write it to a csv file then. I am having trouble creating the nested loop, I just cant seem to get the logic right to add the first element of the orignal list to the new nested list. Here is what i have tried so far

```
lines = [] #original list
matrix = [] #nested list

matrix.append([]) #append blank list
for line in lines:  #loop through lines in text file
    line = list(line.split(',')) #split line by commas to create a list
    line1 = line[0] #create variable that contains user id i.e. first element of list

    for i in range(len(line)): #loop through list
        matrix[i]= line(i)
        matrix[i].append(line1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you appending a whole list by for loop at line 9? you can just do like `matrix=line` and also what is `line(i)` at line 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
user_data = ["user1,follower1,follower2", "user2,follower3,follower4"]
matrix = []

for entry in user_data:
   all_users = entry.split(',')
   user = all_users[0]
   followers = all_users[1:]
   
   for follower in followers:
      matrix.append([user, follower])
```

In this case matrix will contain:

```
[
   ["user1", "follower1"], 
   ["user1", "follower2"], 
   ["user2", "follower3"], 
   ["user2", "follower4"]
]
```

If you have any further questions, let me know.

Comment: Hi Christoph,
This is exactly what i need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
lists=["user","follower1","follower2","follower3"]
matrix=[]
for x in lists:
   if(lists[0]!=x):
    matrix.append([lists[0],x])
print(matrix)
```